# Dcokerfile pass ENV to ENTRYPOINT or CMD

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to start an app based on arg passed at build time

cmd:
`docker build --build-arg profile=live . -t app`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.7-jre-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar

ARG profile
ENV profile ${profile:-dev}

EXPOSE 8080
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /app/app.jar

# ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar", "--spring.profiles.active=${profile}"]   --- not working

RUN echo $profile   <--- here I got the value
#CMD java -jar app.jar --spring.profiles.active=${profile}   --- not working
#CMD java -jar app.jar --spring.profiles.active=$profile   --- not working
CMD ["sh", "-c", "node server.js ${profile}"]   --- not working
```

when I inspect the docker image I got

```
"Cmd": [
            "sh",
            "-c",
            "node server.js ${profile}"
        ],
```

What i'm missing?

Thanks

update:
works with `CMD java -jar app.jar --spring.profiles.active=$profile` and the `$profile` will have the desired value at runtime

Comment: Could you `docker inspect` your container and check the environment variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment replacement doesn't happen in `CMD`. Instead it happens in the shell running inside the container (in your case `sh`, though it's not clear why you've used the json/exec syntax to call a `sh` command).

Documentation on environment replacement is available from: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement

Comment: pfff .... yes, thanks, I started the container but when I pass it to CMD I only `inspect` it so every time was showing the `$profile` var but when I start it the $profile have the expected value, si will work with `CMD java -jar app.jar --spring.profiles.active=$profile` thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this Dockerfile: `docker build --build-arg PROFILE=uat -t app .`

```
FROM alpine
ARG PROFILE
ENV PROFILE ${PROFILE:-dev}
CMD ["ash", "-c", "while :; do echo $PROFILE; sleep 1; done"]
```

Run it and it prints *uat* every second: `docker run -it --rm app`

You didn't mention what exactly is the outcome when you said "not working". Presumed you got empty string or other unexpected value, the environment variable could be in used by the base image. Try another name for your environment variable, or use non-slim version of openjdk image.

Comment: thanks, but if you pass the `CMD` as `CMD some command` dockerwill add the `/bin/sh -c` by default

Comment: hmm ... not related to your answer but I was stuck on some threads treating this behaviout :) thanks again

Comment: You are right if alpine image has an entrypoint - but alpine **doesn't** have one. The CMD will override the command set in alpine image instead.

Comment: This looks essentially the same as the approach in the original question.  How is it different?